# PerspectiveTransform with OpenCv having 4 points project soccer field in 2D

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, homography

I am currently working on a OpenCV project with the goal of finding the position of player in the field. In order to do this I have extracted the lines but now I have to make some perspective transformation in order to get the area that the camera is showing. A good reference is the following links: [Performing Perspective transform when not all corners are visible python openCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53734364/performing-perspective-transform-when-not-all-corners-are-visible-python-opencv) or [Homography from football (soccer) field lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60352448/homography-from-football-soccer-field-lines).
I have a template of a football field and I have manage to treat the first case when the I determine 4 points on the central line. So I have 4 pairs of points(source(given frame) -> destination(in 2D coordinates)).  [image: This is the main image with the points that I determined]

[image: This is the template of a football field and I have retrieved the coordinated corresponding to the 4 points]

Now all I need to do is to get the transformation matrix from the first image and to project in 2D the frame in question, but I don't rely understand from the OpenCV docs and from the results that I get why the following code will not work.

```
   destination_points = np.float32([center_line_top, center_line_top_circle,
                                             center_line_bottom_circle, center_line_circle_center])
            source_points = np.float32([frame_center_line_top,
                                        frame_center_line_top_circle, frame_center_line_bottom_circle,
                                        frame_center_line_circle_center])

            transform_mat = cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(source_points, destination_points)

            maxHeight = self.field.shape[0]
            maxWidth = self.field.shape[1]

            print(transform_mat.shape)
            out = cv2.warpPerspective(display_frame, transform_mat, (maxWidth, maxHeight), self.field)
```

As a result I get a noisy image or just a black screen.(The values of the coordinates are good I have checked them) I also think that the function findHomography() will theoretically return a matrix but it my case it will actually return a tuple of None value and an array of shape 4 with all 0 elements and the program will crash t the warp function.
Any ideas what am I missing or if the approach of the problem is a wrong one?

Comment: the... lawn?... has a light stripe pattern to it. if those are made halfway precisely, you can work with that.

Answer (score 0):

You should use 4 points that are not on the same line.

It should be easy to understand why the computation using aligned points cannot work... just imagine the field rotating around the line... those points would remain the same but you've infinitely many different mappings from projected to 2d.

A perspective planar transform requires 4 points not aligned, 3 only are not enough. You could use the line of the grass trimming as reference (you'd have to guess the position on the map but you should be able to be reasonably precise).

Note also that the map your are using is not correct for that soccer field: I'd guess is a couple of meters thinner... also the len distortion is quite evident so it should be compensated for to get a precise mapping.

[image]

Comment: I am sorry, but I do not follow. In theory it does not matter where the points are in order to get the transformation matrix because there is only one solution.

Comment: You got your 4 points from the screen image and on the 2d map. Now imagine that the soccer field rotates around the midline by 30 degrees in the real world. Your 4 points on the screen would remain the same (the line is fixed) so your input to the algorithm is exactly the same (same 4 points on the screen and same 4 on the map)... but of course the transformation screen->map needs to be different this time...

Comment: Perspective transform is degenerate when all 4 point are on one line. You need to go from a quadrilateral to a quadrilateral, not a line.

Comment: The image is not wide enough to get 4 good points. I see only perhaps 3 unique, non-linear points

Comment: For a perspective planar mapping 4 points are needed. There are infinitely many possible perspectives mapping exactly matching just three points. To get the extra points you could use the intersection of the grass green lines with the circle (of course you'd need to guess what is the location of that line on the 2d map but it shouldn't be to far from the correct spot).